# I cant hear the audio unless i plug in earphones

Tags: audio

Please help. Im always wearing earphones to listen to music on my LG G Stylo but When i tried to listen to music without earphones i heard nothing. I also cant hear anyone on the phone without earphones. I tried putting up the volume but instead of showing the speaker symbol it showed the earphones one. Help!

Comment: May sound stupid, but did you unplug your earphones from the device – or in case of Bluetooth earphones, did you disconnect them? (besides, what kind of earphones we're talking about here: cable-bound or wireless?)

Answer (score 0):

Your device has a physical problem, either the headphone plug in the device is defective or there is something in it causing a short so the phone thinks headphones are still plugged in. Look into the headphone plug with a light and see if you can see anything obvious, but this typically requires a complete disassembly and cleaning or replacement of the headphone plug.

I am not familiar with your specific device, but this can vary product to product from a simple plug-in module, to a micro resoldering job that requires specialized tools.

I would recommend trying a factory default first, although this is usually a hardware issue, it is possible something in software is just "stuck".

If you are not confident performing this procedure, I would suggest contacting a reputable repair vendor or LG.